# Unable to send email using marklogic's xdmp:email function

Tags: email, marklogic

xdmp:email function can be directly used to send the mail in Marklogic.When i am trying to use this function in my Office's machine it is showing me the error.
Error:Cannot resolve hostname.

For this we need to configure SMTP server in our system.But in our machine's we cannot able to configure SMTP server.
so,is there any other way to configure so that it will work.

Thanks,
Vivek

Answer (score 3):

You need an SMTP server as a relay somewhere. A local relay listening only to localhost is a good option, but the relay could be elsewhere.

Another thread on a similar topic: [Sending email using marklogic and xdmp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14826908/sending-email-using-marklogic-and-xdmp)

Answer (score 1):

Just to elaborate a bit on David's answer- the SMTP relay must be an open relay on port 25. There's currently no support for configuring SMTP relay through, say, Gmail servers or internal mail servers that require authentication before relaying.

Because of this, when I need to implement an e-mail enabled MarkLogic server, I configure the SMTP on the local machine (which you said wasn't possible in your environment), but close port 25 to any other traffic. This will allow MarkLogic to send mail, but no other systems can relay from it. If you can't set it up locally, then you'll need to have another mail server that is configured to accept and relay mail from your specific ML instance (typically either using IP tables or configuring the relay by IP address or hostname).